# WebGIS Report Feature with Pictures?

Tags: arcgis-online, widget, reports

I am trying to add a widget to a webmap that will allow users to report wildlife spottings (birds, coyotes, etc). The client (City staff) would like to have to be able to review any reports prior to them being published online. We do want the users to be able to attach a photo to their report.

What is the easiest way to do this? Is it with the Report Feature widget? Is there a way to modify what menus come up with this (I don't need the severity menu)? Is there a way to allow photos to be added to the reports?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to achieve this would be to use the [GeoForm configurable template](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=931653256fd24301a84fc77955914a82) from ArcGIS Online. The GeoForm simply reads the fields of a feature service and asks users questions based around the fields. You can configure the questions as you choose and hide fields as necessary. So within the feature service, you could have a 'verified' field that is hidden from the user. Then in the public webmap/application, you could filter the layer based on the 'verified' field. As you verify the input points, they will appear in the public webmap.

Comment: Is this able to be embedded into the webmap application? We would like it to be 'part' of the webmap, ideally a widget so it is fully interactive with the webmap

Comment: What do you mean by the 'webmap application'? This is a separate application (to the webmap viewer) that links to a webmap in the background. It is more form based, and gives the user a map to choose a location. You could set it up to give the user an option to see the resulting webmap. But obviously they wouldn't see any points they submitted until they are verified.

Answer (score 0):

So I believe I found an easy way to do this. I am using an Edit Widget so that users can easily add or edit points. Within this layer there is a 'status' field that is filled in as 'Pending' by default. The City will have to review any Pending items on a schedule (once a day, week, etc.). The public webmap is set to only display points that have 'Approved' as the Status. Does anyone see issues with this?

Comment: Not in particular. The only UX problem is that people will add a point, and then it will disappear because it is filtered out in the webmap. This might confuse some users.

Comment: Yes, we went over this with the client in detail, and our recommendation was to publish it immediately, and the City needs to have a schedule by which they go in and review/delete as needed (exactly for this reason-we advised them that hiding it will make some users submit multiple posts). They agreed at first, but have now changed their mind and decided they want to approve all posts prior to them going public...